# check which flash plugin version between "internet explorer" or "Other browsers" is installed on the client

Tags: javascript, windows, flash, internet-explorer

if you go on http://get.adobe.com/it/flashplayer/otherversions/ you can find there are two "current" flash player plugin version available for windows

- one for internet explorer
- one for the other browsers

Normally users need only one version installed (or even zero, if they use Chrome and the shipped version with it)

Unfortunately I have an external plugin that communicate with the browser and It needs explicitly installed the internet explorer plugin, also if the user navigate with Firefox.

For this reason I need to check not only if there is a flash plugin installed, but also if is installed the specified explorer version!

Is there a pure-javascript solution to make this check? ATM I loop over all the plugins in the browser searching for a specifed-name dll, but

- it's ugly and I'm ashamed to do something like that
- it's bugged: today I found my check failed, because the adobe-distributed plugin filename changed to from `NPSWF32.dll` to `NPSWF32_11_2_202_235.dll`

thanks